# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'id'

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am getting this warning "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'id'"

on this line

```
_intvalue = [self performSelector:@selector(PostureValueReturn)];
```

here abc is a method

```
- (int)abc
{
    return 3;
}
```

and _intvalue is property

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int intValue;
```

can anyone suggest me how to get rid of that .

Comment: The problem is that performSelector: returns an object so you have to encapsulate your int in an NSNumber object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-performSelector` method returns type `id`.  Is there any reason you cannot actually call the method directly?

```
_intvalue = [self PostureValueReturn];
```